# TCP Data Listener Delayed Acknowledgment problem

Tags: c#, tcp, tcplistener

Hello I am using TCPListener class to listen on a port using [this](https://gist.github.com/WajahatAliAbid/c05caaa9b7a15fed2b47358ae98ac255) code snippet.

The problem I am getting with this code is that it cannot handle more than 40 files in a minute. If we use client to send more than 40 files, the acknowledgements are delayed and the whole process gets delayed and a long queue is built, waiting for messages to be sent and acknowledged. Is there any way to increase the speed of this whole process? Is there a way to have one listener listen on multiple processes/ threads? Can we handle say 100-200 files a minute somehow?

Comment: Man, this code is so wrong in so many places. If you base your application on it there is no chance to get it working. Find a sane tutorial. Since most sockets code is very broken you need to understand the socket APIs yourself and make good decisions.

Comment: Can you refer me some sources which I can use to learn? Also can you please mention how can it be improved?

Comment: @usr I've updated the gist, please have a look.